# Setting specific column tab stops in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I am reasonably familiar with Vim's option for `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, `shiftwidth`, `expandtabs`, etc.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way in Vim to set specific column tab stops.

I need tab stops in the following columns: 7, 11, 14, 17, ... every 3 after that.

Thanks in advance.`

Comment: If this is still important to you: this feature is finally part of vim: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/04958cbaf25eea27eceedaa987adfb354ad5f7fd

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this thread http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Arbitrary-tab-stops-td1211888.html.  Seems like that feature exists for a while as a patch.

```
+                       *'vartabstop'* *'vts'*
+ 'vartabstop' 'vts'    string  (default 8)
+           local to buffer
+           {only available when compiled with the |+vartabs|
+           feature}
+           {not in Vi}
+   A list of the number of spaces that a  in the file counts for,
+   separated by commas.  Each value corresponds to one tab, with the
+   final value applying to all subsequent tabs. For example: 
+       :set vartabstop=4,20,10,8
+   This will make the first tab 4 spaces wide, the second 20 spaces,
+   the third 10 spaces, and all following tabs 8 spaces.
+ 
+   Note that the value of |'tabstop'| will be ignored while 'vartabstop'
+   is set.
+
```

Comment: I heard about a plugin implementing this functionality (of course, by translating pressed tabs into spaces). Don't remember its name though.

Comment: A very nice idea (even though I can't personally think of a use).

Comment: @PrinceGoulash: IDE for fortran 77 often have this.  first tab brings you to column 7 then remaining tabs moves by 4.  sounds stupid now but there should be good historical reasons for working under 80 column limit of terminal or line printer or card or whatever they had then.

Comment: @yosukesabai Ah yes, I was forgetting about Fortran. Now I'm having flashbacks...!

Comment: Actually you are pretty close with the Fortran reference. I need this for editing old Cobol source files which use the above tab stops. I used to use a Windows product called TextPAD that allowed all sorts of customisation based on file type, but my desktop is running Linux now. I might try and find a Linux equivalent to TextPAD.

Comment: Another example would be ledger-cli files. You'd tab two spaces to write an account name, then tab again to a certain column (e.g. 50) to write the amount.